# The basics of batch processing: Where should I start?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, text, batch-processing

I would like to get into batch file processing for Windows, but I have zero experience in this area. If you can point me in a general direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Other potential questions:

- What are the risks to be avoided with batch processing?
- What is the basic structure of a batch file?
- Are there examples of basic types of batch files, where I can put into action?
- What are some basic types of batch commands?

Comment: I made a 5-min tutorial in my spare time, heres the link: http://www.instructables.com/id/Build-a-Batch-Calculator-Advanced-Calculator-v08/

Comment: Not sure why this would be considered 'off-topic'. All of the comments were very useful. This is a forum for collaboration and group learning.

Comment: No @BobHopez, this isn't a *forum*, this is a *Q&A* site about *programming*. Your question is not about programming. You want [superuser](http://superuser.com/about)

Comment: @BobHopez: No, it is a question-and-answer format forum to discuss programming issues. It's not a replacement for documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bach is a very methodical and ordered programming language that runs heavily on the Windows internal CMD or runline commands you're most likely familiar with. The main use of Batch from my personal experience is to use scripts to automate mundane tasks that need to be run every time something happens, for example at user startup.

I bet you could quite easily make a basic script now just buy learning what a) every bactch file should ideally have/need and b) by recognising that by default a batch file will read from top to bottom executing one command after the previous one finishes or fails.

**In answer to your specific questions**:

- The risks to batch processing aren't really existent if you script something properly and test it every step of the way. - I would of said that anyone can easily see your code but third party tools will convert batch to .exe files without a problem.
- I've listed some example codes with a few explanations at the bottom of this answer.
- Again see the bottom of my answer for some basic scripts that will work on your computer (providing it's a version of Windows).
- As I mentioned above any command you can type in to a CMD window will work within a batch file, so you can use `command /?` within a CMD window to check parameters and the way you should write your commands. For example type in to a CMD window `ipconfig /?`.

**Basic Batch File Structure** (Save as test.bat)

```
@echo off
title Test Batch Script
color a
echo.
ipconfig /all
echo.
echo Above is your IP information.
pause>nul
exit
```

**@echo off** - This turns off the CMD prompt until turned on again, without this every action is displayed, on the above script remove the line or turn it on to see the effects.

**title** - This is quite self explanitory, this command titles the CMD window to your choosing.

**color xx** - color xx changes the colour of the background and text, the first value is the text and the second is the window background. - Use `color /?` in a CMD window to find all the possible combinations and choose one for yourself, for example `color 1f`

**echo.** - This will enter a line break in to the file itself, I use this mainly for spacing text or adding a few lines under commands so my text can be seen clearly after commands have run.

**echo** - This will print the line of text you're trying to say, for example `echo hello` will display the text hello in the window.

**pause>nul** - This will pause the batch script from advancing to the next command in the series. - however just using the command `pause` will display the text "Press any key to continue..." using `pause>nul` will remove this message. Not essential but personal preference really.

**exit** - Exit will of course close your program, however not necessary when batch scripting as the script will close when no more commands are left to run, providing that no user input is required.

I feel that I've given you a basic and common batch file using all the most common commands that you'll use nearly every time you make a batch file.

The other answers have listed a lot of resources you can use to learn more. - Batch is an extremely easy language to learn but can get tricky depending on how much user input is required or how automated you want to make something.

Get to grips with my example and replace `ipconfig /all` with different/multiple commands to practice using them within your scripts.

Comment: SamN: Very well organized. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the risks inolvd with batch programming, the worst that can happen is that when working with some files on your computer your batch script may malfunction, causing the files to be either erased or ruined. That is why, it is recommended to back-up all files before testing a batc script.

The basic structure of a batch file varies quite oftenly. When you start of you will mostly rely on `goto` loop structures. Where your script will start of with a series of commands (normally the first one being `@echo off`) and then making the script `goto` diffferent parts of your program.

Later on you will rely on `for` loops and batch calling.

To find some half decent batch app's I recommend you look online as there are some sights which can contain quite a few.

For basic tutorials, I recommend you start of by making simple batch apps to do very basic things like count.

Hope this helped, Mona.

P.S. Here are some I recently uploaded some of my old batch apps on instructables, here are the links:

- [Naughts and crosses](http://www.instructables.com/id/Batch-Game-Noughts-and-Crosses-using-a-save-folder/)
- [Calculator + Tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Build-a-Batch-Calculator-Advanced-Calculator-v08/)
- [Encryption with 7zip](http://www.instructables.com/id/Folder-Locker-bat-Great-for-trolling-and-security/)

Comment: really, so it would not be damaging to accidentally run format (insert drive letter here): when you didn't mean to?

Answer (score 1):

go to http://www.dostips.com/
list of basic commands:
echo hello world ::will write hello world to the screen
echo %time% :: will write the value of the variable time to the screen
cd dir ::will go into the directory named dir
type file.txt ::will print the contents of a file to the screen
dir ::will echo the contents of the current directory to the screen
cd .. ::will goto the parent directory
help :: will show a list of commands
set ::will show all current variables
if "%var%" EQU "hello" (echo is) ::will echo is if the varible var is set to hello
set var=hello ::will set var equal to hello
set /p var=how are you: ::will get input from the user and stroe it in var
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do echo %%i ::will echo 1 to five on the screen
ping host.com ::will check if you can connect to host.con and diplay some results.
copy a.txt dir\dir2\b.txt ::will copy a.txt to the second argument.
move a.txt ..\a.txt ::will move a.txt to the parent directory.
ren a.txt b.pdf ::will rename a.txt to b.pdf
command /? ::will display help on a command

here are some sample files I made:(blank lines matter)
file1:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set NLM=^



set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%

for /f "delims=" %%i in (a.txt) do set a=!a!!nl!%%i

echo %a%


file2:(each for is a single line)

@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if '%1'=='' (echo missing parameter&pause>nul&exit /b)
for /l %%i in (%1,-1,0) do for /l %%j in (%%i,1,%1) do set %%i=!%%i! 
for /l %%i in (0,1,%1) do (for /l %%j in (0,1,%%i) do set nums=!nums! %%j)&echo !%%i!!nums!&set nums=
for /l %%i in (%1,-1,0) do (for /l %%j in (0,1,%%i) do set nums=!nums! %%j)&echo !%%i!!nums!&set nums=

file3:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (a.txt) do set a=%%i&set a=!a:""=! &echo !a!>>new.txt

file4:(for is one line)

@echo off
for /d %%i in (*) do for /f %%j in ("%%i") do (dir "%%i" /b|for /f %%k in ('find "%%j" /v') do @dir "%%k" /b /s|find "thumbs.db" /v)

---

email me if you have questions. I know batch better than any other language and love it. my email is: 12nephi12@gmail.com

have fun!!! ;)